# Get a jenkins' build url from commit/sha

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need a way to retrieve a jenkins' build url from the commit' sha from which it was built.

I need it because I'm working on an automatic jar downloader that given some infos, like branch, repo, and commit, it downloads the desired artifact. But as I asked, I obviously need the sha to retrieve the correct build.

Comment: You'd have to narrow it down a bit. Are you looking inside a specific job or you are looking at all the possible jobs in Jenkins? Do you care if there were multiple builds that built your commit? Do you care if the builds succeeded?

Comment: @Iterokun Inside a specific repo, specific branch. No need to check if the build succeded. There won't be a commit with multiple builds, if the build fails, I will do a new commit with the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jenkins REST API. Iterate over builds `https://hostname/job/job_name/api/json` and for each build check which commit it built `https://hostname/job/job_name/build_number/api/json`.